# Display Problem with absolutepanel with gwt-connector

Tags: java, gwt, connection

I am trying to use GWT-Connector in one of my classes to create the connection point to the widgets. Here is what i have:

```
public class Test extends Composite{

 RequiredData rd = new RequiredData();
 public Test(){
  TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
  t1.setSize("100px", "20px");
  t1.setText("Hi");
  t1.setTitle("textbox");
  
  CustomShapeRet r = new CustomShapeRet();
  
  VerticalPanel v1 = new VerticalPanel();
  v1.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalPanel.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
  v1.setStyleName("vertical");
  v1.add(r);
  v1.add(t1);
  AbsolutePanel ap = new AbsolutePanel();
  ap.setSize("120px", "100px");
  ap.add(v1, 0, 0);
  Diagram d1 = new Diagram(ap);
  Shape s = new Shape(v1);
  s.showOnDiagram(d1);
  initWidget(ap);
 }
}
```

When i run my program it is not displaying the vertical panel properly. Here is how it looks: [http://www.cs.uofs.edu/~sudhakaras2/absolute,jpg](http://www.cs.uofs.edu/%7Esudhakaras2/absolute.jpg) But when i remove the following code:

```
 Diagram d1 = new Diagram(ap);
 Shape s = new Shape(v1);
 s.showOnDiagram(d1);
```

it just works fine.

Question:

1. Is my gwt-connector usage correct?
2. Do i have to add this absolute to rootpanel for connector to work?
3. Is there a way to get around this?

Any suggestion will be of great help.
Thank you.

Comment: 0  vote down
 

+1 for an interesting and very well specified question. I'm sorry I don't know enough to help you. When I did GWT, I always added my AbsolutePanels to the root pane, but I've never worked with this Connector stuff.

Comment: (ignore the "0 vote down" part. That appeared via the site's voodoo.)